# Serilog logged exceptions do not appear in logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-5, serilog

Serilog seems to not log exceptions in delegating exception handler.

Using [ExceptionHandler delegate property](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6255c1ed960f5277d2e96ac2d0968c2c7e844ce2/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerOptions.cs) to catch and log exceptions, but it seems that anything that I log there does not appear in the logs (only in debug output and other parts like EntityFramework Core still logs to the serilog, but not logs in the exception handler).

Tried to change scope/format etc (move logging to the background), but that did change anything and [serilog diagnostics](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) did not provide no additional information.

Using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory and .NET5 REST API.

> Note: If I try to log something in exception handler constructor, those logs appear in serilog, but while logging cached exceptions in method body, those logs do not appear in serilog.

```
loggerFactory.CreateLogger(this.GetType()).Log(
    httpException.LogLevel,
    0,
    exception,
    logMessage,
    httpException.UserFriendlyMessage.LogArgs);
```

Comment: Why would you create a logger inside of the callback? Also you should show the surrounding code because it's not clear what the context is

Comment: This is more of an example how it is created, in code it is created once in the base class. And what would be more useful to show specifically? Because there is a lot of code (~300 lines: inner source code goes from NuGet where callback is registered there and then logging happens in other exception converter class). In short singleton exception converter method (where logging happens) is called in RequestDelegate ExceptionHandler.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing or knowing the context of your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.